# stop hyphenation for table column

Tags: tables, hyphenation

I have this table

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabulary} 
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]
\begin{tabulary}{\textwidth}{lLLLrr}
\hline
\textbf{type} & \textbf{author} & \textbf{title} & \textbf{about} & \textbf{year} & \textbf{ref} \\ \hline
book & David Salomon and Giovanni Motta & Handbook of Data Compression & general & 2010 & [1] \\
article & Senthil Shanmugasundaram and Robert Lourdusamy & A Comparative Study Of Text Compression Algorithms & text compr. & 2011 & [2] \\
article & Kitty Arora and Manshi Shukla & A Comprehensive Review of Image Compression Techniques & image compr. & 2014 & [3] \\ \hline
\end{tabulary}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

This is how it looks like:
[image]

I don't want to have hyphenation in the column *"about".* But I still want to have line breaks where necessary. So, the words "general" and "image" shall not by hyphenated (nor any other word in this column), but there shall be a linebreak between "text" and "compr." as well as between "image" and "compr.".

Hyphenation shall be possible in other columns. I want the name *"Shanmugasundaram"* to be hyphenated, also long words in the title shall be hyphenated (not shown in my example).

I tried other symbols for columns definition (other than l, L, r), but then the table looks ugly and hyphenation still happens. I also tried `{\raggedright general}` instead of `general`, but this has no effect.

What can I do to avoid hyphenation in the column *"about"*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the hyphenation penalties `\hyphenpenalty` and `\exhyphenpenalty` to an “infinite” value for that particular column as mentioned in the [TeX FAQ](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-hyphoff). However, this causes overlapping in the case of long words (notice the 4th row) which may be prevented by setting a specific width of that column.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabulary} 
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]
\begin{tabulary}{\textwidth}{lLL>{\hyphenpenalty=10000\exhyphenpenalty=10000}Lrr}
\hline
\textbf{type} & \textbf{author} & \textbf{title} & \textbf{about} & \textbf{year} & \textbf{ref} \\ \hline
book & David Salomon and Giovanni Motta & Handbook of Data Compression & general & 2010 & [1] \\
article & Senthil Shanmugasundaram and Robert Lourdusamy & A Comparative Study Of Text Compression Algorithms & text compr. & 2011 & [2] \\
article & Kitty Arora and Manshi Shukla & A Comprehensive Review of Image Compression Techniques & image compr. & 2014 & [3] \\
article & Kitty Arora and Manshi Shukla & A Comprehensive Review of Image Compression Techniques & imagefhdfjk compr. & 2014 & [3] \\\hline
\end{tabulary}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Addendum:

You may also use the [`tabularray`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray) package which allows manual linebreak in a cell.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]
\begin{tblr}{
    width=\textwidth,
    colspec = {lX[l]X[l, 1.5]lrr},
    row{1} = {font=\bfseries}
}
\hline
type & author & title & about & year & ref \\ \hline
book & David Salomon and Giovanni Motta & Handbook of Data Compression & general & 2010 & [1] \\
article & Senthil Shanmugasundaramasks and Robert Lourdusamy & A Comparative Study Of Text Compression Algorithms & {text\\compr.} & 2011 & [2] \\
article & Kitty Arora and Manshi Shukla & A Comprehensive Review of Image Compression Techniques & {image\\compr.} & 2014 & [3] \\
\hline
\end{tblr}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

This package makes handling tables very easy and convenient. Note that there is better spacing between the rows by default.

Answer (score 1):

I'd take a different approach: your columns are too narrow for being readable. My suggestion is to set authors and title in the same column and to use abbreviations for the “about” column.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}l>{\raggedright}Xccc@{}}
\toprule
Type & Author and Title & About & Year & Ref \\
\midrule
book &
  David Salomon and Giovanni Motta \\
  \itshape Handbook of Data Compression &
  G & 2010 & [1]
\tabularnewline\addlinespace
article &
  Senthil Shanmugasundaram and Robert Lourdusamy \\
  \itshape A Comparative Study Of Text Compression Algorithms  &
  TC & 2011 & [2]
\tabularnewline\addlinespace
article &
  Kitty Arora and Manshi Shukla \\
  \itshape A Comprehensive Review of Image Compression Techniques &
  IC & 2014 & [3]
\tabularnewline
\midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
\multicolumn{5}{@{}l@{}}{G: general; IC: image compression; TC: text compression}
\end{tabularx}

\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]